# How to merge branches, omiting files' "delete mode"

Tags: git, merge, git-branch

I have two branches.

In a branch one I have dozens of files in "delete mode" and I want to merge it with a branch two, which has these files normally. (not all of them)

I want to merge the branch two to the branch one and be able to see the files, which are in the branch two in the branch one again.

Is it possible?
Now when I try to merge them, the result is "Already up-to-date.", but I can't see the files.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do? Do you want to merge without the deleted files being merged? What command did you run that gave you "Already up-to-date"? Maybe also post the output of `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.

Comment: Basically I want to make all files that are visible in branch two, to be visible in branch one